# Generate Script In SQL Server 2008 Is Very Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Time of Get Script From My Database In SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 is about 45:00 Minute.
count of tables : 380
Count of views : 89
Count of SP : 109

Comment: Is it also very slow if you right click on a table or view and generate creation script there as well? On usual systems this take a few seconds max.

Comment: No Create Single Script From Table OR View Is Very Fast.

Comment: Googling around, it seems that this is a common problem. Are you scripting from SSMS? An option might be to use PowerShell where you have a finer control on SMO scripting options and where you can script all objects at once.

Comment: I Use SSMS to get script of Database. How I Can use SMO To generate script?

Comment: I wrote a command-line tool that generates scripts using SMO http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/smoscript-0-19/ hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look your tempdb, sometimes, the operation is slow, maybe sqlserver divide space for other objects.

Comment: I Get Script From SQL Server 2012 Management Studio On This Database again and it was very fast. but get script from sql server 2008 R2 still is slow.

Answer (score -1):

This speed will depends on you system's or server's configuration. If you system's configuration is low in that case it will takes much more time. Second this will depends on you database size suppose you are saving images or pdf files in binary mode in database in that case it will takes long time to generate scripts.....

Comment: My System Property is:Windows:Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) X5660 @ 2.80GH Installed Memory: 16 GB SystemType: 64Bit Operation System   CPU: 12 Core

Comment: Size of Database is About 30GB

Comment: I generate script with no data. In SQL Server 2008 R2 Execute About 45:00 Minute and in SQL Server 2012 Execute About 30 Second.